# AngularJS, Fabric.js objects as list

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to implement a sortable ojact list similar like a layer list in photoshop using the codebase of the fabric.js kitchensink example. For the sortable function of the list I am using also JQuery UI. I am tryin to adopt some code from another project, but apparently I am doing something fundamentally wrong, since I am not able to get a populated list.

My controller is looking like this:

```
kitchensink.controller('LayersController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'canvas', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, canvas) {

    $scope.objects = canvas._objects || [];

    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        items: '.object:visible',
        scroll: false,
        containment: 'parent',
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.item.data('start', ui.item.index());
        },
        update: function(e, ui) {
            var start = ui.item.data('start'),
            end   = ui.item.index();


            obj = canvas.getObjects()[start];

            if ( ! obj) return;

            if (end > start) {
                //send object forwards by the amount of objects it passed
                for (var i = 0; i < (end - start); i++) {
                    canvas.bringForward(obj);
                }
            } else {
                //send object backwards by the amount of objects it passed
                for (var i = 0; i < (start - end); i++) {
                    canvas.sendBackwards(obj);
                }
            }

            $timeout(function() {
                canvas.renderAll();
                start = false; end = false;
            });
        },
    }

    $scope.setAsActive = function(object) {
        if (object) {
            canvas.setActiveObject(object);
        }
    };

    $scope.toggleVisibility = function(object) {
        if ( ! object) return;

        if (object.visible) {
            object.set({ visible: false, evented: false, selectable: false, hasBorders: false, hasCorners: false });
        } else {
            object.set({ visible: true, evented: true, selectable: true, hasBorders: true, hasCorners: true });
            canvas.setActiveObject(object);
        }

        canvas.fabric.renderAll();
    };

    $scope.deleteObject = function(object) {
        if (object) {
            canvas.remove(object);
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    };

    $scope.toggleLock = function(object) {
        if ( ! object) return;

        if (object.locked) {
            object.set({
                locked: false,
                selectable: true,
                evented: true,
                lockMovementX: false,
                lockMovementY: false,
                lockRotation: false,
                lockScalingX: false,
                lockScalingY: false,
                lockUniScaling: false,
                hasControls: true,
                hasBorders: true
            });

            canvas.setActiveObject(object);
        } else {
            object.set({
                locked: true,
                selectable: false,
                evented: false,
                lockMovementX: true,
                lockMovementY: true,
                lockRotation: true,
                lockScalingX: true,
                lockScalingY: true,
                lockUniScaling: true,
                hasControls: false,
                hasBorders: false
            });
        }

        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}])
```

This is how I am trying to get the list in my template – I have stripped out some code related to show/hide and delete from here that I am using in the controller to keep it more simple:

```
<div id="objects" class="">
    <ul class="objects-panel list-unstyled" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="objects">
        <li class="" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-click="setAsActive(object)" ng-if="!object.ignore">
            <p>Blah</p>
        </li>

        <li ng-if="!canvas.fabric._objects.length" class="text-center">
            <p>No layers yet.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

The problem was here in the code. Declaring the canvas was wrong here:

```
kitchensink.controller('LayersController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'canvas', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, canvas)
```

Comment: if the problem is populating the list, i would start removing the jquery part and the ng-if on the list of `Blah`, just in case they are interfering.

Comment: Thanks Andrea! You pointed me in the right direction. The problem was the "declaration" of the canvas in the controller. I have edited my post with the solution. But since you pointed me in the right direction, I will set your answer as the right one :-)